# Why does Xdebug not get my connection, using PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I can't seem to get my **Xdebug** to work with **PhpStorm**.
It works fine for **PHPUnit** tests, so I'm assuming it's an issue with my local server.

Now for those tests I always have a Configuration for the Test-Class in question (those seem to auto-generate). I do not have one of those prepared for the class I'm currently trying to test (I seem to remember it working at some point and never having an explicit Configuration, but my memory is hazy).

My Debug Configuration:
[image: My Debug Configuration]

My CLI-Interpreter (having Xdebug registered):
[image: My CLI-Interpreter (having Xdebug registered)]

My xdebug.ini Config:
[image: My xdebug.ini Config]

I'm trying to debug a Magento application running on localhost, port 80.

Comment: I have `xdebug.mode = coverage` when I run unittests, I believe that has to be 'debug' for usage in PHPstorm

Comment: So you are trying to run a php file in debug mode from php storm?

Comment: @Martijn tried it with only coverage. Didn't work, sadly.

Comment: @MaartenDev I'm trying to listen for Debug Connections through PhpStorm.

Comment: did you installed a xDebug browser extension? check if a xDebug cookie is coming from the browser

Comment: @vladkatz Yes and there does seem to be a cookie coming in called XDEBUG_SESSION. Sounds about right.

Comment: @Hurrpadurr just to make it sure, did you checked it in the browser or on the server (local).

Comment: 1) Please post the whole Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output (may also be `xdebug_info()`) captured in the same way as you are trying to debug (CLI or a web page) 2) Show your Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session. Does it try to debug at all? It should give some hints. 3) What are you trying to debug when it does not work: a web page or a CLI script?

Comment: @LazyOne Oh, okay, I think we're getting closer. There is no dedicated Xdebug section in my phpinfo() and it is not mentioned in the "Additional .ini files parsed". Log is empty. So I guess it's not running on the server then?

Comment: @Hurrpadurr I think you have written the xdebug info on the wrong .ini file. the CLI and the web server .ini files are not the same. find out where the web .ini file is located and put the xDebug info in. should solve the problem

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` via CLI where debug works, as I understand) and web page (where it does not). Show the top most table with the general PHP info -- it will show what config file is used in each environment. Right now (based on your 2nd screenshot) you may have Xdebug loaded&configured only for CLI. If I'm right then you need to do the same for a web server PHP config as well (it's quite common these days on many Linux and Mac setups)

Comment: phpinfo() via CLI is the same as php -i, correct? In that case both seem to be referencing the same .ini File. The only difference is that Xdebug is not included in the web-page setup. I can provide screenshots in the main post, if that helps?

Comment: @Hurrpadurr You need to provide the info that would allow us to help YOU. Right now, based on your limited info (as we do not know your whole setup) and overall experience, I may *guess* that Xdebug may not be loaded (or configured differently) when you request the web page. To prove my guess:please provide the requested info: `phpinfo()` output for both CLI and Web page environment. P.S. Yes, `php -i` will produce the same as PHP script with `phpinfo()` inside (in a CLI environment only).

Comment: I gave it another look and as it turns out you were 100% correct. I have no idea why it ever worked on the web page before in the first place, but I'm very happy it works now.
I learned a lot, thank you for your patience!

Comment: please provide a valid answer for the post, for future questions and people whom will encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that my CLI and Webserver were using different configurations. Thus tests were working fine (using the CLI configuration) but debugging incoming connections did not work (using the Webserver configuration).

The configuration used can be checked via phpinfo() (or php -i for the CLI).
In my case the CLI configuration could be found under /etc/php/{version}/cli and /etc/php/{version}/fpm respectively. Both contained a folder called conf.d in which Symlinks to the desired modules have to be placed (for me they could be found under /etc/php/{version}/mods-available). I added the Symlink for Xdebug in my .../fpm/conf.d configuration and it worked like a charm.

Thanks again for the helpful comments.